# How to register the class that implement interface to Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, webapi

I have `Dapper` models that I use with [`ColumnAttributeTypeMapper` code](https://gist.github.com/kalebpederson/5460509).

This attribute helps to map between SQL column names to the properties on the model.

One thing though, is I need to tell Dapper to know about this Model class so I need to do this code for each model:

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(FooModel), new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<FooModel>());
...
```

I try to automate this by creating IModel interface:

```
public interface IModel {}
```

And using extenstion to find all class that implements IModel and map them:

```
public static class WebApplicationExtensions
{
    public static void MapModels(this WebApplication app)
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            
        var classes = assemblies.Distinct().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => typeof(IModel).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract);

        foreach (var classe in classes)
        {
            Dapper.SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(classe, new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<classe>());
        }
    }
}

app.MapModels();
```

But the build throw error: `'classe' is a variable but is used like a type`.

I also try to do the following:

```
  Dapper.SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(classe), new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<classe>());
  Dapper.SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(classe), new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<typeof(classe)>());
```

But it did not work either. How to make dotnet to "register" those models to Dapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Type.MakeGenericType** like this:

```
foreach (var classe in classes)
{
    Dapper.SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(classe, (ITypeMap?)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<>).MakeGenericType(classe)));
}
```